# Statistical comparison between two curves

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, anova, curves

I have two time course experiments of the same study, and I want to determine if the time course curve is statistically significant or not. Let's say I treated a group of people with drug A, measure it at some time points. And I also treated a group of people with drug B, and measure it at some time points. I do not want to specify an explicit model (don't want to do a linear or non-liner curve fitting), just want to know if they are different or not. I can do Mann-Whitney on every sampling time, or maybe repeated measure ANOVA, but is there any well know statistical techniques to deal with this ?

Comment: Can you clarify? When you say "I don't want to specify an explicit model," what do you mean? Every statistical test has a model behind it. Also, you note that you have 2 time course experiments. Do you mean 2 separate groups from the same study, or 2 trends from different studies? I think you need to rephrase the question a bit to get a meaningful response.